# Is there a way to prevent Cypress to fail if zero test files are found?

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing

Question, I've a situation where I filter with a RegExp the Cypress tests, in the Cypress plugins folder.
This check is done on a javascript level with a custom lib that check with `git diff` the updated files of the branch I am in, during the execution of Cypress tests.
This functionality works properly both locally and within a Jenkins pipeline.

There are some cases where this RegExp filters all tests out, meaning: there is no need to run any Cypress tests (what it means is that it was touched some code that is not affecting anything regarding components of a UI library, so any Cypress tests is necessary).

Is there a way to prevent in this case, the failure of Cypress suite?
I would love that my `package.json` script that run Cypress tests is executed but without failure of the command if zero tests are found.

```
$ cypress run --headless
[ '**/time.**' ]
Can't run because no spec files were found.

We searched for any files inside of this folder:

cypress/integration/functional
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! .......
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ....... test:cy:run:functional script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! .npm/_logs/2021-08-20T06_41_30_883Z-debug.log
Error: Command failed with exit code 1: npm run test:cy:run:functional

{
  command: 'npm run test:cy:run:functional',
  exitCode: 1,
  signal: undefined,
  signalDescription: undefined,
  stdout: undefined,
  stderr: undefined,
  failed: true,
  timedOut: false,
  isCanceled: false,
  killed: false
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is add a dummy/token/smoke test that always succeeds and never filters out, e.g `expect(true).to.eq(true)`.

Share any details of the test selection? If it's on test timestamp, you will need to touch the dummy test prior to each run.

---

[Cypress Module API](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/module-api#Examples) allows more control over the test.

Useful blog [Wrap Cypress Using NPM Module API](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/wrap-cypress-using-npm/)

Possible suppression of error - a bit of a punt, depends if the error originates from Cypress or your own script.

```js
cypress.run(options)
  .then((runResults) => {
    if (runResults.status === 'failed') {
      // Cypress could not run, something is terrible wrong
      console.error(runResults.message)

      // Suppress fail if error is "no spec files found"
      const exitCode = runResults.message.contians('no spec files were found') ? 0 : 1;
      return process.exit(exitCode)
    }
  })
```

Comment: I was thinking about that too, but I was wondering if there was a flag (didn't see in Cypress), or whatelse to suggest Cypress not to fail if zero tests found.

Comment: I think I saw an example using one of the experimental run events, see if I can find it. e.g [after-run-api](https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/after-run-api)

Comment: this `after:run` is executed when run is finished, the error described above occurs before. I get what you have in mind. still, can't find a proper plugin yet

Comment: Process isn't clear from the question - what's RHS of `test:cy:run:functional`?

Comment: You've tagged `jenkins-pipeline` - does the problem occur when run locally?

Comment: it happens both in Jenkins and locally. Let me try to improve the question